# is there a way to get video call link from google calendar with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm developing google script that uses google apps services and calendar api.
Is there a way to get the video call id from CalendarEvent object?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using the default [CalendarApp Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app), you will need to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (which you should enable in the Script Editor by selecting Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enable it in the Google Developers Console.) then you can get the **[hangoutLink](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations)** of an event.

Here's an example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarId = 'calendarId';
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, event.hangoutLink);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! 

And is there a way to get to the advanced calendar service event starting with event object from calendar app service anyhow, or do I have to re-design everything to use advanced calendar service only?

Comment: Yes, that depends on your use case, for instance you can get all the event details with the default CalendarApp Service, then just create a function to retrieve the `hangoutLink`by the `eventId`.