# How do I get a Google Meet link from google calendar with google apps script for specific dates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I would like to retrieve Google Meet links on the calendar using Google App scripts. I understood that this requires the Advanced Calendar Service and have enabled it. I tried this from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992770/is-there-a-way-to-get-video-call-link-from-google-calendar-with-google-apps-scri). It works but I would like to specify a date range. How do I do that?

Comment: Try using the API explorer to figure out what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To specify the date range with the Advanced Calendar Service you can use `timeMin` and `timeMax`

Thereby:

`timeMax`:  Upper bound for an event's start time

`timeMin`:  Lower bound for an event's end time

Those parameters are arguably not very user-friendly and it might be easier to use the method [CalendarApp.getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#geteventsstarttime,-endtime) which returns events returns events that start and end during the specified time range.

Sample how to combine `CalendarApp` with `Advanced Calendar Service`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarId = "primary";
  var now = new Date();
  var twoHoursFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var events = CalendarApp.getEvents(now, twoHoursFromNow);
  if (events.length != 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
      var event = events[i];
      var eventId = event.getId().split("@")[0];
      Logger.log(eventId);
      var eventSummary = event.getTitle()
      var hangoutLink = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).hangoutLink;
      Logger.log (" Event: " + eventSummary + ", link: " + hangoutLink); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of your comment.

Comment: I did not mean to post the comment. Still very new to this. But I did manage to use timeMax timeMin to get the desired results. So thanks a lot for your answer!